# syntax error while compiling sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a new table for my database with sqlite:

```
String CREATE_ARCHIVE_TABLE = 
"CREATE TABLE {0} ({1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
" {2} TEXT NOT NULL, {3} TEXT NOT NULL, {4} TEXT NOT NULL, {5} INTEGER);";

db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(CREATE_ARCHIVE_TABLE,AItext.TABLE_NAME,AItext._ID,
        AItext.TITLE,AItext.MESSAGE,AItext.DATE,AItext.TYPE));
```

with the interface:

```
public interface AItext extends BaseColumns {
  String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";
  String TITLE = "title";
  String MESSAGE = "message";
  String DATE = "date";
  String TYPE = "type";
  String[] COLUMNS = new String[]
  { _ID, TITLE, MESSAGE, DATE, TYPE };
}
```

but I have the following exception and I can't see the error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTEGER": syntax error: , 
while compiling: CREATE TABLE archive_contacts_name (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
AUTOINCREMENT, message INTEGER, name TEXT NOT NULL, phone TEXT NOT NULL,
check INTEGER, note TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Comment: You have `message INTEGER` in your Table definition, but I'm pretty sure you want that to be a `TEXT` too

Comment: `check` is reserved keyword. I believe it can not be use as column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aim has said, [CHECK](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) is in fact a SQLite Keyword that cannot be used as a column name.

> A CHECK constraint may be attached to a column definition or specified as a table constraint. In practice it makes no difference. Each time a new row is inserted into the table or an existing row is updated, the expression associated with each CHECK constraint is evaluated and cast to a NUMERIC value in the same way as a CAST expression. If the result is zero (integer value 0 or real value 0.0), then a constraint violation has occurred. If the CHECK expression evaluates to NULL, or any other non-zero value, it is not a constraint violation. The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.
>
> CHECK constraints have been supported since version 3.3.0. Prior to version 3.3.0, CHECK constraints were parsed but not enforced.